# Spring Boot and Apache Kafka complex examples

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am looking to get the Spring Boot and Apache Kafka complex topics/scenarios examples. Whatever I found on web was very basic and similar demo.

Does anyone has Spring Boot and Apache Kafka example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also looking for solid examples. And I could not find anything concrete but "hello world"... Then I just realized that I'm overlooking the Confluent's documents.

1. [How to Work with Apache Kafka in Your Spring Boot Application](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-spring-boot-application/)
   This is literally "hello world" but might be a good warm-up for beginners.
2. [Spring for Apache Kafka Deep Dive – Part 1: Error Handling, Message Conversion and Transaction Support](https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-1-error-handling-message-conversion-transaction-support/)
3. [Spring for Apache Kafka Deep Dive – Part 2: Apache Kafka and Spring Cloud Stream](https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-2-apache-kafka-spring-cloud-stream/)
4. [Spring for Apache Kafka Deep Dive – Part 3: Apache Kafka and Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-3-apache-kafka-and-spring-cloud-data-flow/)
5. [Spring for Apache Kafka Deep Dive – Part 4: Continuous Delivery of Event Streaming Pipelines](https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-4-continuous-delivery-of-event-streaming-pipelines/)

I think the [Confluent Platform's](https://www.confluent.io/blog/category/frameworks) blog is a real hidden gem for the developers. There are lots of cool topics besides of example/tutorials. To name few of them:

- [Spring for Apache Kafka – Beyond the Basics: Can Your Kafka Consumers Handle a Poison Pill?](https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-kafka-can-your-kafka-consumers-handle-a-poison-pill/)
- [Advanced Testing Techniques for Spring for Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/advanced-testing-techniques-for-spring-kafka/)
- [How to Use Schema Registry and Avro in Spring Boot Applications](https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-avro-in-spring-boot-application-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

please refer this tutorial. there are some steps.
https://howtodoinjava.com/kafka/spring-boot-with-kafka/

Comment: Yes thanks I refereed to that already, it just covers two things. I need more detailed and complex stuff with Spring boot and Apache Kafka. Any books? I'd love to purchase that !

Comment: you can follow this instructor's courses. this https://www.udemy.com/course/apache-kafka/#instructor-1 but not with spring. you can collect the all topics about Kafka and please do search on google those topics with spring. it's better.